# Where should I store static resources when I build spring-boot app by gradle?

Tags: spring, gradle, assets, spring-boot

I've found samples that stores static files in `/src/main/webapp/` and `/src/main/resources/static/`. What's the difference and what's the best place to store static files in `spring-boot` app?

Comment: Spring has a [blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) describing different options for a Spring boot app

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your resources are in `src/main/webapp` that suggests you are building a WAR archive. And for a JAR `src/main/resources` is more appropriate (eg in `/static` if it's a boot app). It's up to you though if you want to put stuff in non standard places - you just have to configure the build system to understand what you mean.