# Build jar with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot

jar-file with gradle.

**My project structure:**

[image]

The problem is, that when i build a jar with gradle, he doesn't put the red marked src-folder into the jar-file, so that my application cannot be seen in the browser. How can i build it WITH this folder?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757393/where-should-i-store-static-resources-when-i-build-spring-boot-app-by-gradle

Comment: As explained with @DanielScott's link, webapp isn't a valid folder when building a spring-boot jar. Use src/main/resources/static or src/main/resources/public instead

Comment: Ok. But when i put my .jsp files into the resources folder springboot cannot find them.

Answer (score 2):

**application.properties**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

move your jsps to

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp/
```

http://hillert.blogspot.com/2016/03/spring-boot-with-jsp-in-executable-jar.html
https://github.com/ghillert/spring-boot-jsp-demo